# How to match and change values from two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I'm really still learning php and this time can't implement this piece of code. I need some help please.

I have this query:

```
$query = tep_db_query("select c.categories_id, c.categories_image, cd.categories_name,
 c.parent_id from " . TABLE_CATEGORIES . " c, " . TABLE_CATEGORIES_DESCRIPTION . "
 cd where c.parent_id = '0' and c.categories_id IN ('25', '29', '41') and
 c.categories_id = cd.categories_id order by cd.categories_name ASC");
```

As a result, I got this array:

```
Array ( [41] => Acura Parts and Accessories [29] => Honda Exterior Accessories 
[25] => Toyota Engine Parts)
```

I have created this short category name array:

```
$shortNames = array('25' => 'Toyota', '29'  => 'Honda', '41'  => 'Acura');
```

I need to instead of echo the long category name in the following code, match the id and echo the short name.

```
while ($categories = tep_db_fetch_array($categories_query))  {
<a href="<?php echo tep_href_link(FILENAME_DEFAULT, 'cPath='.$categories['categories_id']); ?>">
<?php echo $categories['categories_name']; ?>
</a>
}
```

I have been looking at some foreach samples but can't really get into this.

Thank you!!!

Comment: So, did you store the result of the initial query into $categories array? (it's not very clear to understand)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if I understood what you are trying to do, it would be something like this:

```
while ($categories = tep_db_fetch_array($categories_query)){

    $categoryId = $categories['categories_id'];
    $shortName = $shortNames[$categoryId];
    $href = tep_href_link(FILENAME_DEFAULT,'cPath='.$categoryId);

    echo '<a href="'.$href.'">$shortName</a>';
}
```

Comment: *hmm*, this is what I also hoped OP would want. You have my upvote. :-)

Comment: Thanks Rajdeep! I hope he can clarify this for us

Comment: @ nanocv - I'm sorry, I missed the while. I have added the code to the post. Thank you.

Comment: @nanocv WOW it works perfectly, thank you, you really made my day.

Comment: @glen You are welcome! And remember to keep your code simple ;)